# "Tengo miedo" or "tengo miedo de que"?

Tags: queísmo-dequeísmo

Which one is correct?

> Tengo miedo que me echen del trabajo.

Or:

> Tengo miedo de que me echen del trabajo.

Comment: Hello, Kelly! Welcome to our site. This is a good question, but remember to include always the option you think is correct and why do you think is correct, as proof that you have at least researched something about what you ask. Besides, you will have better chances to get upvoted if you do so. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, to help you identify if you have to write *que* or *de que*, just substitute the relative clause with "algo" (literally, "something"):

> Tengo miedo algo.
> Tengo miedo de algo.

Here we can clearly see that the first sentence is quite ungrammatical, hence the verb needs a *de* that has to be kept when you switch back to your original sentence:

> Tengo miedo de que me echen del trabajo.

If you still don't see it clearly, we can just look for the word in the *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* (DPD), although you need to read Spanish for that:

> **[miedo](https://www.rae.es/dpd/miedo)**. 1. ‘Temor’. El complemento que expresa la causa del miedo puede ir introducido por *a* o *de*.

So the reason for the fear must be introduced in Spanish by the *a* or *de* prepositions. So you can say:

> Tengo miedo a que me echen del trabajo.
> Tengo miedo de que me echen del trabajo.

I would say that I see *de* more frequently than *a*, though it depends on the specific sentence. The DPD also says:

> Cuando el complemento es una subordinada introducida por *que*, no debe omitirse la preposición.

So it clearly specifies that you must not omit the preposition even if the reason for the fear is specified by a relative clause.